# How can we have sync between different Azure File Shares across regions?

Tags: azure, azure-files

I need to sync files between 2 Azure File Shares, each in a different region across globe.

I have the need to be able to allow users in each region to read/write to their respective regional Azure File Shares.

I know that RA-GRS is not yet available for Azure Files, but even if it were, my requirement won't be met because I need the ability to be able to allow users to read/write to their respective shares from their region.

Comment: what's your purpose? sync between azure file shares or allow users in each region to read/write to their respective regional Azure File Shares?

Comment: both sync between AFS in different regions, while allowing local users in each region to be able to r/w to their respective file shares.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [azcopy sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-sync) to sync blobs between two storage accounts. It works with File Shares as well but read the warnings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-files#synchronize-files). This is one way sync based on the last modified timestamp of the files.

If the files on the destination are going to be modified, you will have to write a custom script with the file comparison/retention logic.